# Cannot refactor in IntelliJ due to Node.exe

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, intellij-idea

Working in Windows on IntelliJ with Angular project I cannot sometimes refactor files by renaming them or move because Node.exe process prevents IntelliJ from doing so.

I need to kill Node.exe processes every each time I need to do such tasks. Anyone?

Comment: Please could you elaborate on this? what process is it?

Comment: Like I wrote above, Node.exe

Comment: This sounds more like a bug which should be reported in their [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)